# Why would "SELECT * FROM user" throw a syntax error?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, syntax

```
String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=CSTest.mdb";
String query = "SELECT * FROM user";

OleDbConnection connection = null;
try
{
    connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    log("Database Connected!");

    OleDbCommand test1 = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
    OleDbDataReader test2 = test1.ExecuteReader();
    log(test2.ToString());
}
catch (OleDbException error)
{
    log("Something went wrong: " + error.Message);
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
    log("Database Disconnected.");
}
```

The output:

```
Database Connected!
Error occurred: Syntax error in FROM clause.
Database Disconnected.
```

Why am I getting that error with such an easy query? I tried adding a semicolon at its very end, but nothing changed.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and an Access Database.
Do you think the problem has something to do with the Access 2013 Engine I just installed? I haven't any other office-related program except for OpenOffice on my computer.

Comment: I've updated the title of the question to be a specific, summary of the exact problem you're having. This helps people know how far you've got, defines the problem well (which always helps with getting the solution) and helps to remind people of when they've had a similar problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User` is a keyword so u should enclose it with `[]`

```
SELECT * FROM [user]
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point based on exception message.

Comment: @SonerGönül it is saying error in FROM clause..after from its table name with keyword USER..so I guess it can be the pblm

Comment: yea, it solved my problem... i'm such an idiot. tnks a lot

Comment: @fabbroniko u r welcome bro :)